# Installing nvidia driver 396 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm having several issues installing nvidia drivers (or just anything with open gl and/or vulkan)

Either I will try to install drivers with ubuntu (third party option from boot disc and then switching drivers in software update settings), and the game I test with (the linux port of saints row the third) will have ridiculously low fps, even at low settings.

Or I'll try installing it via the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa in terminal and the process will get stuck at 87%. the specific terminal line it's getting stuck at is:

```
writing new private key to '/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv'
```

I want to make sure I can get past this step before anything else.

Comment: try to install 'ukuu' from http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html and install latest kernel and after switch/install 396 nVidia driver

Answer (score 2):

Nvidia releases a new driver 396.37  (09/07/2018).
This is currently available only in rpm and not available on the graphics driver ppa.
It is impossible to compile cuda 9.2, because the old version was remove and is now based on a new driver.

Comment: Hi Opotmans! Welcome to askUbuntu! Please format and and answer you r post according to https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer  and https://askubuntu.com/editing-help. I really don't understand what you want to state.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I removed all what I had of Nvidia libraries and reinstalled it from Software & Update. Before doing so, I disabled Secure Boot from BIOS but I'm not sure if this step really helped.

Did you try rebooting, and after that, installing the Nvidia Drivers from Software & Update ?

**Software & Update / Additional Drivers**

Comment: So I did eventually get this to work: I disabled secureboot during the Ubuntu install, and then when you restart you *need* to make sure secureboot is still set to disabled when the dialogue comes up just after the BIOS.